# Reading in characters followed by numbers c++

Tags: c++, arrays, text, character

So I have been looking online for a way to read in characters followed by numbers and so far everyone has been using string functions. However, I am only allowed to use C-Style character arrays and I have been having trouble on my program when I read in the file.

my text file is this:

```
23
11

Java 2 linux 3 fear 0 pool 2 do 0 red 1 lock. 1 I 0 random 2 computers, 0 not 0 the 0 open 2 car! 2 C, 0 lack 0 of 0 dog 1 green 2 C++ 0 bottle 2 wrong, 2 them. 0

5 1 10 21 9 6 21 11 13 16 20
```

So far my program printed out:

```
11 23
Java 2
```

However, I want it to print out everything. Any advice? Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct pieces {

char word[5];
int jump;
} ;

 // Main Function
int main ()
{
// declare variables
int wordCount[2];
int keyCount[2];
int numKeys;
int numWords;
int keyAmount = 1;
int wordAmount = 23;
pieces cypher[wordAmount];
char filename[10];
ifstream inData;

  //prompt user for input file

cout << " Enter file name: ";
cin >> filename;

inData.open(filename);

if(inData.is_open());
{

    // read list of names into array

    for ( numKeys = numWords = 0; numKeys < keyAmount; numKeys++){

        inData >> wordCount[numKeys] >> keyCount[numKeys];

        for( numWords = 0; numWords < wordAmount; numWords++){

        inData >> cypher[numWords].word >> cypher[numWords].jump;

        }
    }



    // print out unsorted onto console

        for ( int i = 0; i < numKeys; ++i){
    cout << wordCount[i] << " ";
    cout << keyCount[i] << "\n";
    cout << cypher[i].word << " ";
    cout << cypher[i].jump << " ";



    }

}
inData.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be simpler to create your own `string` class with a dynamically resizing character array, and then use one of the solns that uses a `string`

Comment: where did you get keymount = 1?

Comment: @AndyG
So would I create a dynamic resizing character array for every time I am reading in the words?

Comment: @Raindrop7 If I change that number to anything else it just keeps printing out numbers and not even a character.

Comment: do you want to store words in an array and numbers in another one?

Comment: @JohnnyB: You want to create `string`, plain and simple. It should have a default character buffer size (which you can make pretty small in your case, say 16) and it should track this size. It should support the `>>` and `<<` operators which will read and write to a filesystem. When reading from a filesystream, get characters from the stream and discard whitespace (like spaces, tabs, carriage returns and newlines), and then append characters to the buffer until you read whitespace or end of the stream. The buffer should resize itself when an insertion happens but there's no more space.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Yes! I need to use the bottom numbers separately as a key to decipher some files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reading code is working correctly, but the for loop that prints out the contents of `cypher` is not correct. Change it to this to see everything from the file:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < wordAmount; ++i){
    cout << cypher[i].word << " ";
    cout << cypher[i].jump << " ";

}
```

Do a similar `for loop` of 2 iterations to see contents of `wordCount` and  `keyCount`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your goal but if you just want to stream your text into your console window and print it as it is written and formated in a file you can use stdio.h and c functions.

Try to use fgetc(); to read symbols into char variable followed by printf(); and then check when fgetc() is ' ', then check a 2nd symbol to see if it is a letter or a digit. if it is either of these increment your counter by one and wait for another ' '.

so. wait for ' '. check next symbol. if a digit d++; if a symbol c++; wait for the next ' '; if it is ' ' again wait again. if it is a digit add 1 to d if it is a symbol add another one to c. but it is for actual words only. if your file contains words written in l33t and a word starts with a digit like 1amth3b3st. your counter will fail.